# GPU usage,как узнать в процентах в текущий момент для разных карт

Tags: c#, gpu

Вопрос в том,чтобы узнать загрузку в процентах в текущий момент 2 GPU Nvidia,пробовал perfomancecounter,там только под cpu после попыток я понял,можно по идее как-то в openwhardwaremonitor но как?или другой способ какой-то?

```
    public readonly Sensor[] loads;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clocks = new Sensor("GPU Core", 0, SensorType.Clock, this, settings);
        textBox1.Text = clocks;
    }
}
```

Подключил OpenhardwareLib.dll и Sensor недоступен из-за его уровня защиты пишет

Comment: Добавте в вопрос ваши попытки как код,

Comment: добавил,не коннектится с библиотекой

Answer (score 0):

Я не силен в получении характеристик системы,но думаю можно сделать что-то типа
1.Узнаем кол-во видеокарт(далее ВК))
2.Определяем для их загрузки место в массиве
3,5.Обновляем значения в связи с изменениями
3.Выводим каждое значение в массиве с учетом названия видеокарты
4.Повторяем с пункта 3,5